# Why the values of the numpy vector do not change after modification?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numbers, numpy-ndarray

I took a screenshot of my screen during debugging, and I surrounded what was wrong: I surrounded in red in my script the subtraction, and in my debugging window the values of 'old_parameters' and 'new_parameters'. As you can see, the values of 'old_parameters' and 'new_parameters' do not change after subtraction. How can it be please?
I share the photo below:
[debugg_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU06G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because they are much smaller numbers to have any impact on `10^19` times larger number  `-8.2 e^-20` vs `-2.77 e^-1`